# Start a Windows application and feed in username and password automatically

Tags: powershell, cmd, passwords, autologin

I have a set of apps that I would like to open on startup. They require a username and a password in order to login. Once you feed those in and press LogIn, a confirmation message asks to confirm whether you want to login or not.

Can this be done using CMD or PowerShell ?

eg:

```
> Start <path>/App1 | Username ; Password | Press OK
> Start <path>/App2 | Username ; Password | Press OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful for you:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
function win32UserDLL {
<#
// set focus to window 
#>
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        $mainWindowHandle = (Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle,
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('SetFocus', 'BringWindowToTop')]
        [String]$action = 'SetFocus'
    )

    $win32UserDLL = Add-Type –memberDefinition @” 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
    public static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);
“@ -name “Win32SetFocus” -namespace Win32Functions –passThru


    switch( $action ) {
        'SetFocus' {
            [void]$win32UserDLL::SetFocus($mainWindowHandle) 
        }
        'BringWindowToTop' {
            [void]$win32UserDLL::BringWindowToTop($mainWindowHandle) 
        }
    }
}

$appName = "myApp"

$handle = (Get-Process | where { $_.ProcessName -like $appName }).MainWindowHandle | where { $_ -ne 0 }

$handle

win32UserDLL -mainWindowHandle $handle -action SetFocus

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Username")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Password")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```